# How to get a signature file as is from a Json file

Tags: java, json, security, file-io

I have a scenario where I need to generate a public key file and signature file for actual file using java security API.

Unfortunately when I dserialise Json file content using below snippets

For writing singnature file into Json file

```
    JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createJsonGenerator(new ileWriter(new File(jsonGenFile)));
    jGenerator.writeStartObject();              
    jGenerator.writeFieldName("sig"); 
    jGenerator.writeStartArray(); 
    String st = " ByteArray ";
    byte[] a = st.getBytes();
    jGenerator.writeBinary(a);
    jGenerator.writeEndArray();
    jGenerator.writeEndObject();
    jGenerator.close();
```

For reading from json file

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj;
try {
    obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(jsonGenFile));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    // loop array
    JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("sig");
    Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        byte[] aa = iterator.next().getBytes();
           // System.out.println(aa);
        }
    }
 } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

What am I doing wrong here?
What is the right way to handle this kind of scenarios.

Needed expert advice.

Comment: "Unfortunately when I dserialise Json file content using below snippets"... what happens?

Comment: the encoding would be distrubed hence it wont work.

Comment: Hence we need to use Base64.encode and decoding option, it would solve the problem.